# Load IFrame with web page with zoom and scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I'm using the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Receiver</title>

    <style type='text/css'>
      html, body {width: 100%; height: 100%; padding: 0; margin: 0;}
      body {background: #FFF;}
      #iframe {width: 100%; height: 100%;}
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <iframe src='' frameborder='0' scrolling='yes' marginheight='0' marginwidth='0' seamless='seamless' id='iframe'></iframe>

    <script type='text/javascript'>
      window.onload = function() {
    updateFrameScale('some url here', 0, 200, 0.2);
      };

     function updateFrameScale(url, scrollX, scrollY, scale) {
        document.getElementById('iframe').src = url;
        document.ready(function() {
        $("html,body").scrollTo(scrollX, scrollY);
        var scaleVar = 'scale('+scale+')';
        document.body.style.webkitTransform =  scaleVar;    // Chrome, Opera, Safari
        //document.body.style.msTransform =   scaleVar;       // IE 9
        //document.body.style.transform = scaleVar;     // General
    });
      }  
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

The `IFrame` is loaded with the web page, but there's no scroll or zoom. I'm a JavaScript noob, so maybe there's something really clear but I can't see it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank to the help of @iJack user I solved my question. I used his code for the scale problem. About the scrolling I used a workaround using a div element. Here the final code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Receiver</title>

    <style type='text/css'>
      html, body {width: 100%; height: 100%; padding: 0; margin: 0;}
      body {overflow:hiddent; background: #FFF;}
      #mydiv {border-style: inset; border-color: grey; overflow: scroll; height: 100%; width: 100%}
      #iframe {width: 100%; height: 1000%;} <!-- The trick is to set the height here to 1000% -->
    </style>
    <script
        src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.0.min.js"
        integrity="sha256-RTQy8VOmNlT6b2PIRur37p6JEBZUE7o8wPgMvu18MC4="
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id='mydiv'>
      <iframe src='' frameborder='0' scrolling='no' marginheight='0' marginwidth='0' seamless='seamless' id='iframe'></iframe>
    </div>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
      window.onload = function() {
        updateFrameScale('https://wikipedia.org', 0, 100, 1);                  };
     function updateFrameScale(url, scrollX, scrollY, scale) {
        var iframe = document.getElementById('iframe');
        iframe.src = ''; //reset
        iframe.src = url;
        $(document).ready(function() {
              var scaleVar = 'scale('+scale+')';
              document.body.style.webkitTransform =  scaleVar;
              document.getElementById('mydiv').scrollTop = scrollY;
              document.getElementById('mydiv').scrollLeft = scrollX;
        });
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```